# What curve in 2d has property that the curvature increses linearly with $x$

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature

I am looking for a curve such that curvature at point should be proportional to $x$ coordinate.

Let us say that the curve is given by (x,f(x)). Then the curvature is

\begin{eqnarray}
\kappa = \frac{y''(x)}{(1+y'(x)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}

And if curvature is to depend on $x$ linearly, then

$$\kappa = \mu + \lambda x$$, where $\lambda, \mu$ are constants.
I know that when $\lambda$ is equal to zero the solution is circle. But what is the general solution of the problem?

Assuming $y'(x) \ll 1$, the solution will be a cubic polynomial. This does not sound a nice solution.

Comment: Looks like you want the clothoid.

Comment: Some geometric thoughts. What kind of domain for $x$ do you imagine? Can you sketch such a curve (roughly - ignore the differential equation). For $\lambda > 0$, as $x$ grows the curvature will increase - will the curve may bend back on itself? The circle isn't the graph of a function.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician, many thanks for pointing out the curve.

Comment: @EthanBolker, a cubic polynomial for example, between x(-1,1) $y = x(1-x^2)$

Comment: The clothoid has curvature increasing linearly with arclength, not with $x$. As Ethan points out, a graph with the property you're describing won't exist globally; but you should be able to find local solutions by solving the ODE. Plugging it into Mathematica yields a very ugly general solution in terms of elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the notation for intrinsic curves, $s$ for arc-length and $\psi$ for tangential angle, where $\tan\psi=\frac{dy}{dx}$, curvature is given by $\frac{d\psi}{ds}$.

So we have $$\frac{d\psi}{ds}=kx=\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{d\psi}{dx}\cos\psi$$

$$\implies\frac 12kx^2+c=\sin\psi=\frac{\tan\psi}{\sec\psi}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}}$$

Solving this DE would give the general solution.

So, for example, in the case where $c=0$ and $k=2$, this boils down to finding $$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx$$ which is expressible in terms of elliptic functions.